# Can Mule generate a WSDL based on output?

Tags: wsdl, mule

I want to create a WSDL based on the output I have, can Mule generate this automatically, or do I have to define the WSDL manually?

Comment: Dataset and WSDL doesn't have much in common. Please make the question clear.

Comment: updated, I want to generate a WSDL from Mule, is this possible?

Comment: What do you use to expose this service in Mule?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you create a service in mule and want to get a wsdl for that service. You can get a WSDL for that service by using the service url inconjuction with ?WSDL

If your service is

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice
```

then a WSDL can be obtained by the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice?wsdl
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I add ?wsdl to the url I am still directed to the service, not the wsdl

Comment: then you have not created a real SOAP service. post your config here. That would help to get more insight into the issue.